# Quadratic Expectation...sorta?

Tags: expected-value, matrix

I am trying to find $E_\alpha[\beta^TD_\alpha X^TXD_\alpha\beta]$ where $D_{\alpha} = $diag$ (\alpha_i)$.  $\beta$ is p by 1, $X^tX$ is p by p, and $D_\alpha$ is p by p.  Note, the expectation is over $\alpha$, not $\beta$! I would like to better understand the results of a paper that finds the above expectation in terms of $E[\alpha\alpha^T]$ and $E[\alpha^T]$.  I have changed the problem slightly from what is in the paper, as I would like to understand how to tackle an expectation like this in general- not just see the answer to the problem I am currently working on.  Thanks for any advice you can give!

Comment: First note that the linearity of expectation means you don't have to worry about the $\beta$ terms.  Then, why not calculate explicitly what happens when $p=2$?  That ought to indicate what the general formula looks like.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether the other variables, $\beta$, and $X$, have any dependence on $\alpha$. Keep in mind that the expectation is simply the integral (or sum, if $\alpha$ is discrete) over all values of $\alpha$ weighted by the probability of each value, so it's a linear operator.

If $X$ and $\beta$ are independent of $\alpha$, you can take the expectation inside the product. For my own convenience, let $R = X^T X.$ Then,

$$
E_\alpha[\beta^T D_\alpha R D_\alpha \beta] 
= \beta^T E_\alpha[D_\alpha R D_\alpha] \beta.
$$

Now,
$$
\begin{split}
[D_\alpha R D_\alpha]_{k l} &= \sum_{i,j} \alpha_k \delta_{k i} R_{i j} \delta_{j l} \alpha_l \\
&= R_{k l} \alpha_k \alpha_l.
\end{split}
$$

So $D_\alpha R D_\alpha = R \circ (\alpha \alpha^T),$ where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product (i.e. element-wise product of two matrices of equal dimensions). So,

$$
\begin{split}
E_\alpha[D_\alpha R D_\alpha] &= E_\alpha [R \circ (\alpha \alpha^T)] \\
&= R \circ E_\alpha [\alpha \alpha^T].
\end{split}
$$

I know using the Hadamard product is not a nice matrix-multiply-ish way to express it, but that's the only way I could see to isolate the $\alpha$s from the other factors, to take the expectation. It might help if you write out the entire expression explicitly as a sum of over four indices (representing four matrix multiplications [using the $R$ convention]), then wrap it in the expectation $\int [\hspace{1mm}]p(\alpha) d^p\alpha$, and see where you can swap the sums and the integrals.

Of course, if $\beta$ and $X$ depend on $\alpha$, then keeping the expectation over the whole expression is as general as you can get.

Comment: I upvoted this a while ago, but I would like to explain that the reasons why include (a) the clarity of this account and (b) the simplifying thrust of the analysis, which first replaces the apparently complicated $X^\prime X$ by $R$ and factors out the distracting $\beta$ terms.  This is a nice way to proceed in general, thereby responding to the original request for a general approach to such problems.